# Change users to a custom domain which are synced to Azure AD from local AD

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

We have a local domain in our office which is set up as testing.local, so each user is say john@testing.local.

In Azure we have setup a new Azure AD called testing (testing.onmicrosoft.com) and have added a custom domain cloud.testing.com which has been verified and set as the primary domain.

We then used Azure AD connect and its express settings to sync our office domain to the cloud which has worked fine apart from our users are now john@testing.onmicrosoft.com instead of john@cloud.testing.com.

Does any one have any idea how to set users synced from a local domain to use the custom domain (cloud.testing.com) instead of azure default (testing.onmicrosoft.com)?

We has the custom domain set as primary when we run the sync so I am not sure what else I could have missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either a) change the UPNs in your AD or b) create a custom sync rule in AAD Connect to transform your @testing.local UPNs to @cloud.test.com UPNs on the fly.

AAD Connect does not currently support renaming users. You can however use the Azure AD PowerShell module, specifically the `Set-MsolUser` cmdlet to do a one time pass of your users and change their UPN to the desired format in the cloud.